# Creating own object model (like that of Excel VBA)

Tags: c#

I am new to Stackoverflow & *hope members will forgive me if I ask a wrong question*. 
I have just started learning C# and classes. A very fundamental question that came to my mind is how can I create an object model (hierarchy) of my classes. Let me explain :

Lets say, I have a class called **PEX**. When I instantiate this class it should contain some properties, methods & another class called **Windows**. Now Windows will also contain some method & property & another class **Window**.

class Windows & Window should not be accessible directly but rather only through PEX class.

Windows will return all Window instances....basically like the Excel Object model.

I should be able to do foreach(Window window in PEX.Windows) { ....} and other such stuff...
I also read inheritance but cannot get this object model in place.

```
public class PEX
{
    public _Windows Windows;

    public PEX()
    {
        Windows = new _Windows();
    }
}

public class _Windows
{
    public _Window Window;
    private int _count;

    public _Windows()
    {
        Window = new _Window();
        _count = 10;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
    }       
}

public class _Window
{

    private string _title;

    public _Window()
    {
        _title = "Roshan";
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to write some code already, or are you completely new to the concepts of inheritance and oop? (And yes, as it stands currently, I think this is a "wrong" question, but at least you acknowledge that it might be one, which is a huge leap in the right direction :) )

Comment: I have placed a snippet of what I have tried, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is usually referred to as the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This is where the parent class is responsible for creating the child classes. Also, you might want to avoid using `Window` as a class name. Here is a simple example where a class has a nested class.

```
public class PEX
{
 public List<PexWindow> Windows { get; set; }//list of windows you can foreach on
 public PEX()
 {
  Windows = new List<PexWindow>();//constructor to make sure the list can be worked with
 }

 private class PexWindow
 {
  public int Param { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but declaring the `Windows` property as a `List<>` *might* be problematic, depending on the circumstances. Because not only does it allow `foreach` iteration, but also `.Add`-ing new `PexWindow` instances to the collection, which might or might not be desired.

Comment: @stakx - That is a valid point. There is kind of a lack of detail that specific which is why I chose to leave it as a `List` (which is publicly accessible through the current `PEX` instance). Perhaps a `private IEnumerable` or equivalent could be more appropriate, I suppose it would really just depend on the specifications and implementation at that point.